# deploying winforms application with MS access Database

Tags: winforms

I am developing a winforms application with MS access database, the project working properly before publishing, but after the deployment the following error message appears, [image]

and my database doesn't accept any updates

Comment: Include the database in your publish... It literally says it cannot find it.

Comment: The problem lies hear, the database is included in the application files

Comment: can you please post the whole exception text?

Comment: Check the path in the exception, let us know if the database file is actually there.